# The browser or gateway element with ID 'Safari1Plus' cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis, user-controls

I have a stranger error on my machine, I have a .browser file in app_browser of my application and it has the following lines:

```
browsers>
<!-- Disable the Menu Adapter for the Safari/Chrome browser-->
<browser refID="Safari1Plus">
    <controlAdapters>
        <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
                         adapterType="" />
    </controlAdapters>
</browser>
```

When I try to load the application I get the error in the subject but none of my colleagues (We are all using the same code base) gets it.

I have an instinct that the error is linked to IIS and I spent a whole day trying to get my head around it to no success.

To make this work in the meantime, I have replaced the safari1plus with default, but the underlaying problem is that I have a gridview on one of my pages that doesn't display anything on my local machine and it does work on other devs machine.
I am not sure as to why or the cause of this but it looks like it is a configuration based issue and maybe one or two people have had to deal with this.

Anyone with an idea is welcome.

Obviously the OS is Win 7 64 bits, with VS2010 Professional and IIS7.

also I have checked the content of Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers and  Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers and also on the Framework64 Dir and all looks the same(compared to other devs machine)

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected this was an IIS issue and I accidentally resolved it by checking all the settings of all the web apps. My application has 7 apps that shares the same Data layer.

The way I resolved it to make sure that all apps use ASP.Net v2.0 integrated pool as application pool, obviously this doesn't make any sense, but that is what worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

You should look up the exact `refId` in the corresponding browser definitions files located at `<windir>\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64]\<ver>\CONFIG\Browsers`.

For .NET 4.0, the `refId` is `WebKit` and not `Safari1Plus`.

Comment: @ClaytonGulick: thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the answer so you can remove your comment now.

Answer (score 1):

In mi PC C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers\safari.browser the line for safari is

```
<browser id="Safari3Plus" parentID="Safari">
```

then i just change `<browser refID="safar1plus">` to `<browser refID="safari3plus">` in BrowserFile.browser in App_Browsers on web project and it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is due to browser definitions inheriting from definitions that existed on the .NET framework v2 and no longer exist on v4.

Delete the browser definition file in the \App_Browsers folder.

Or

Make sure that all apps use ASP.Net v2.0 integrated pool as application pool.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue while trying to run my sharpoint 2010 foundation app in windows 10 machine.

I resolved in following way:

1. in IIS > Application Pool > Select required app pool > right click > Basic
   Settings > Change ".Net CLR Version" to "v2.0.50727" and saved.
2. Go to Sites > select site>Double click "Authentication" > Enable basic
   authentication.

The same should work for any asp.net application which expects version 2.0 as target version.